# JSoup works in an Android Activity, but not as an object in the Activity

Tags: java, android

I have created an Android app that I would like to supply with some info scraped from a page. I used JSoup, and was succesfully able to scrape all of the HTML, and place them into the proper data structures in a console project, with a single class name Scraper.java.

My next step was to port this Scraper.java into my Android app. To do this I simply wanted to make a Scraper object in my activity that I need the html info for. This didn't seem to work, and I was getting an error that seems as if it was trying to tell me that Android didn't like this external class trying to connect to the internet.

Giving up I very dirtily dumped all of the code from Scraper.java into my Activity class and got it to scrape the data fine, and it connected without any issue.

The problem now is that I realize I want to access that complex data in other Activities, and it really would be much simpler for me to just go back to trying to have an external Scraper.java file so I can share an object of it rather than all of the data types inside of it.

So my question is, what do I need to do to let Android know that it doesn't need to freak out, and can let my external Scraper.java file connect.

I have allowed the permission for internet in the manifest so I am lost as for what to do from here.

Comment: Show us your code and show us your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had a very silly error, and my code is functional now. Sorry for the long delay for my response I was very busy last night.

The problem that I had was when I ported over my console version I still left in a main method in the Scraper.java file which was clashing with my Android app. I cleaned up the code even more, and am able to reference a Scraper.java object very easily.

To remedy sharing an instance of an object once I have created I think I am going to implement Parcelable with my Scraper.java file so that I can share the instance easily amongst multiple activities. For anyone that is interested I will be referencing http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html